# How to go about from ASP.Net to Classic ASP for new project

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

How to go from ASP.Net to Classic ASP; I have been assigned to new project which is in Classic ASP and I have never worked on Classic ASP but have exposure to .NET

Comment: What kind of project is this?  Is there a specific reason that "Classic ASP" is to be used?  How big is the project?  For the past 2+ years I've been working on migrating a Classic ASP webiste to ASP.NET and I can't figure the reasons why someone would want to go in the other direction.

Comment: Be careful with Classic ASP and other legacy technologies in your career.  I don't find it annoying to work in those technologies, but future employers will find it problematic to hire somebody who doesn't have recent experience with newer technologies.

Answer (score 7):

You need to get a new job immediately. :) Unless you're converting a small asp application to asp.net? In which case, [this](http://www.asp101.com/articles/paolo/asp2aspnet/default.asp) may help. And even then, I'd still consider a new job.

I would take half a day to research why ASP.NET is an improvement on classic asp. Also point out your own skills, which are ASP.NET, and therefore why an ASP.NET project should be faster to develop.

Present your research (even if it's just in an email) to your employer. If they still want to use classic asp for **new** projects take your ASP.NET skills elsewhere.

I have seen good people sent down legacy roads, the results are never good for them.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I do agree with Joe R and Azamsharp's sentiments. The benefits of using something more up-to-date are innumerable. But I also know that's completely unhelpful, since you're just trying to get the job done that's been assigned to you.

Two tips: I find http://www.devguru.com to be an excellent site for reference. It has detailed information on both asp and vbscript, and it's well-formatted and easy to use.

The other tip is to spend the time (it won't take much) to ensure you can step through your classic asp pages using your current version of Visual Studio. In IIS config --> Home Directory tab --> Configuration --> Debugging --> enable asp server-side debugging. This will allow you to insert a breakpoint in your asp script (just a statement saying "stop") that will give you a prompt to invoke the VS debugger. You will also need to configure your local web site to run under your network identity instead of the default anonymous user.

Doing this considerably lessens the pain of working in classic asp, when you have no other choice.

Answer (score 2):

A language is a tool, not a lifestyle. Ignore the fanboy comments. A job is a job, make your suggestions if applicable but if you are a programmer, then program. If you were a mechanic looking for work and some one wanted to hire you working on bmw's and gave you the opportunity to learn, but you are used to mercedes, would you turn it down? asp classic is easy to learn and you can master the whole language, unlike *.net. Just read through a vbscript reference guide and then learn the asp collections. Not much to them but they will get the job done and that is what matters to the client.

Comment: I don't think BMW vs Mercedes metaphor holds up.  More like BMW vs AMC.

Answer (score 1):

Why in the world your employer wants to do that?? You need to ask him this question. That is like saying we are abandoning all the cars and let's go back to those carts which are pulled by horses.

Comment: I don't think the project is going from ASP.NET to ASP.  I think Anwar is an ASP.NET developer who has been asked to work on a classic ASP application.

Comment: If that is the case then you need to convince your client to move the legacy ASP application to ASP.NET.

Comment: Why should he convince the client to move a legacy app to a new technology?  That could be way more expensive and time consuming than updating/maintaining the existing app.

Comment: Depends how big the application is? Always a good idea to stay little current with the technology since sooner or later there will be no one who can support the legacy system.

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer to the following questions:

- Are you starting from scratch (unlikely?) or is it a matter of smaller modifications?
- Are you stuck with coding in VBScript or can you choose JScript?
- Will there be lots of backend/business logic?
- Will there be many forms with DB storage requirements?

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for your suggestions, comments, and concerns. Yes, it is unlikely that person/company be moving an application from ASP.Net to Classic ASP.  I have been recently assigned a Classic ASP project to fix and enhance few modules along with other projects am handling.  Since this would be my first venture in Classic ASP, I wondered how do I go about it like debugging etc.  As you suggested to configure IIS to get debugging on will certainly of great help; Please do suggest your experiences with Classic ASP and its differences to ASP.Net like event handling, intellisence,

Comment: Please do suggest your experiences with Classic ASP and its differences to ASP.Net like debugging, event handling, intellisence, scripting, etc. Thanks again to all for your concern and help.

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP is very simple scripting language, which is the good and bad of it. There is no event handling, as far as I know.  When a classic ASP page loads, it executes the code in a straightforward line-by-line style.  You can have functions in VBScript to help with your code/logic.  But there are no pageloads or server-side (postback) onclick methods/functions.

You will have html forms that when submitted with go to an ASP page.  This page will execute the code to process the form data and perform the necessary tasks.

Classic ASP is very straightforward and simple, which is the charm of it to me.  What you see is what you get.

A great resource I use for finding different types of info on VBScript is at the W3Schools website:

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/